# How to extract rows from multiple CSV files and add the file name to a new file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have over 500 csv files all under the same directory and they all look like:

```
20190430_1.csv
IC1905; 5063; 2351; 4845; 4487
IC1906; 7489; 4135; 4879; 4315
IC1907; 1478; 9638; 8521; 3214

20190501_1.csv
IC1905; 5663; 2301; 4045; 4087
IC1906; 7479; 4035; 4049; 4305
IC1907; 9512; 7532; 4521; 3654

20190502_1.csv
IC1905; 6063; 4351; 4145; 4187
IC1906; 6489; 3135; 4179; 4215
IC1907; 7485; 9685; 1245; 3256
```

I was hoping to extract row 1 & 3 from every csv file and to insert a new column for the file name, also to remove “_1” if possible.
This is what I expected:

```
20190430; IC1905; 5063; 2351; 4845; 4487
20190430; IC1907; 1478; 9638; 8521; 3214
20190501; IC1905; 5663; 2301; 4045; 4087
20190501; IC1907; 9512; 7532; 4521; 3654
20190502; IC1905; 6063; 4351; 4145; 4187
20190502; IC1907; 7485; 9685; 1245; 3256
```

I am new to python so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Do you just need to create another file, or do you want to get the data into a `DataFrame`? If there's no real reason to use `pandas`, other than as a glorified `.csv` reader/writer, perhaps the tag isn't needed?

Comment: @ALollz sorry I didn't make it clear. I do want to get all data into `DataFrame` and save it as a new csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os` to get all of the files, here I'll assume it's a directory of just those `csv` files you want to read, but it may contain other file types.

Read in each file, select the 1st and second row, and assign the filename handle as a column:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = 'path_of_your_csv_files'
l = []
for file in [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.csv' in f]:
    fname = file.split('_')[0]
    l.append(pd.read_csv(path+file, sep=';\s', header=None, engine='python').iloc[[0, 2], :].assign(name=fname))

df = pd.concat(l)
```

#### Output `df`:

```
        0     1     2     3     4      name
0  IC1905  5663  2301  4045  4087  20190501
2  IC1907  9512  7532  4521  3654  20190501
0  IC1905  6063  4351  4145  4187  20190502
2  IC1907  7485  9685  1245  3256  20190502
0  IC1905  5063  2351  4845  4487  20190430
2  IC1907  1478  9638  8521  3214  20190430
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that all data needs to be put into `dataframe` then save as a new `csv`.  I know I can use `df.to_csv` to save the file and grateful if you can show me how to use `dataframe` in this case

Comment: @Nat, yes in that case you should just be able to do `df.to_csv('fullpath_of_your_file', sep='; ', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Make sure all csv files are located in same directory as py file. Otherwise provide a relative path to that file.

```
import csv
filenameList = ['20190430_1.csv', '20190501_1.csv', '20190502_1.csv']

l=[]
for file_name in filenameList:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        examples = list(reader)
        l.append(examples[0])
        l.append(examples[2])

with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter='\n')
    writer.writerows(l)
```

Comment: Make sure your `output.csv` is in a different folder(not under the same folder if you are not using a `filenameList`.

Comment: @Pax Thank you for your answers. But I have too many files, I can't list all out the filenames.  So it would be great if the code can loop over the entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your files in folder `./desktop/test` and you are in your home folder. Using `pathlib` module, and `pd.read_csv` reads in only row 1 and 3. `glob` to pick only csv files. Add column `name` and listcomp them together. Finally, `pd.concat`

```
import pathlib    
p = pathlib.Path('./desktop/test')

df_list = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', header=None, prefix='Col', 
                        skiprows=lambda x: x not in [0, 2]).assign(name=f.name.split('_')[0])
                for f in p.glob('*.csv')]

pd.concat(df_list)

Out[178]:
     Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4      name
0  IC1905  5063  2351  4845  4487  20190430
1  IC1907  1478  9638  8521  3214  20190430
0  IC1905  5663  2301  4045  4087  20190501
1  IC1907  9512  7532  4521  3654  20190501
0  IC1905  6063  4351  4145  4187  20190502
1  IC1907  7485  9685  1245  3256  20190502
```